# Passing command line arguments to console application does not work

Tags: c#, console-application, command-line-arguments

I can't pass arguments to my console app.
I tried it like this:

```
App.exe arg1
App.exe "arg1"
App.exe
```

When I run the app with arguments, the app quits running without any messages.

When debugging there is nothing in `string[] args`.

My C# project is a plain .net 4.5.2 command line project.
My OS is Windows 10 x64.

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Setup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                using (PowerShell psInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    string cmd = "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force; " +
                                 "echo \"Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force\"; echo \"\"; " +
                                 "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force; ";

                    psInstance.AddScript(cmd);

                    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = psInstance.Invoke();

                    Console.WriteLine(psInstance.Streams.Error[0].ErrorDetails.Message);

                    foreach (var item in PSOutput)
                    {
                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Will not work
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please include the code you have written for App.exe. It is probably something simple.

Comment: I have edit my question.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing arguments to your app? Assuming you run this from Visual Studio, is there anything in the text box *Command line arguments* on the *Debug* tab in the properties of your project?

Comment: @Marcus please see whether my answer helps you. If it doesn't, I will be very happy to help solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 8):

I simplified your code a bit further; namely we will now look at

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfArguments = args.Length;

        if (numberOfArguments > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Count: {numberOfArguments} First: {args[0]}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No arguments were passed.");
        }

        Console.ReadLine(); // Keep the console open.
    }
}
```

so that we get an output either way.

---

Running this without any further ado will yield

> No arguments were passed.

However, in Visual Studio, by going into

> Project -> Properties -> Debug

we will now provide some command argument lines for debugging.

[image]

Running the program now will yield

> Count: 3 First: -first

---

For real world use, you can then run the app (e.g. from the command line) like this:

```
app.exe -one /two three foo
```

and it will still get all of the command line arguments:

> Count: 4 First: -one

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you can share the code.

Sample program to print zero position argument will be :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it from commandline

```
ConsoleApplication1.exe argument1
```

[image]