# System.TimeoutException in System.IO.Ports.dll error

Tags: c#, console, serial-port

I wrote a console c# program that sets parameters(I gave parameters from project->debug option) I am trying to get data from ethernet and serial port.

I set args parameters successfully but program gets **timeout error** at `string filename = args[4];` **Console opens suddenly** and act as if it is in infinite loop bu there is no loop.(error occurs before reading while)

For those who want to read what are those parameters; [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3OF6.png) = IP, [2] = port number, [3] = port name(COM3), [4] = filename.

**[EDIT]**
Timeouts are to prevent data loss considering I might be getting data from both connections at the same time from ethernet and serial port.

Also I want to say adding `DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessReceivedData);` istead of while has no benefit since again it happens before the while loop.

Does anyone have any idea?

[image: error and parameters I gave]

```
static int Main(string[] args)
        {

            int err = 0;

            if (args.Length == 5)
            {
                IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(args[1]);
                int CmdPort;
                if (int.TryParse(args[2],out CmdPort))
                {
                    string filename = args[4];//takes filename 

                    String root = @".\\"; //DEFAULT EXE PATH ROOT
                    string path_combined;
                    path_combined = Path.Combine(root, filename);
                    StreamWriter sw;
                    try
                    {
                        sw = File.AppendText(path_combined);
                        p = new SPWrapper(IP, CmdPort, args[3], sw);
                        if (p.Init())
                        {
                            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                            {
                                p.GetMessage();
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                            }
                            p.Close();
                        }
                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                    catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
                    {
                        System.ArgumentException argEx = new System.ArgumentException("File creation failed!", ex);
                        err = -2;
                        throw argEx;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    err = -1;
                }
            }
            if (err!=0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Enough Arguments");
                Console.WriteLine("Logger IP Port ComPort FileName");
            }
            return err;
        }//end of main
```

> Here is my other class

```
 public class SPWrapper
{
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort CmdSerialPort;

    public DateTime lastComm = DateTime.MinValue;
    public UdpClient udpClient_Cmd;
    public volatile bool _enabled_Cmd;
    public static int Ethernet_Packet_Header_Length = 14;
    private IPAddress IP { get; set; }
    private int Cmd_Port { get; set; }
    private string SerialPortName;
    private StreamWriter swLog;
    private bool _closing = false;
    private IPEndPoint IPE_Cmd;


    private void CloseEthernet()
    {
        udpClient_Cmd?.Close();
    }

    private void CloseSerialPort()
    {
        if (CmdSerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            CmdSerialPort.Close();
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _closing = true;
        CloseEthernet();
        CloseSerialPort();
        swLog = null;
    }

    private bool InitilizeSerialPort(string portName)
    {
        try
        {
            CmdSerialPort.PortName = portName;
            CmdSerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            CmdSerialPort.ReadTimeout = 10; // 10milisecond read timeout

            CmdSerialPort.Open();
            if (CmdSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool InitializeEthernet()
    {
        bool retVal = true;
        IPE_Cmd = new IPEndPoint(IP, Cmd_Port);
        try
        {
            udpClient_Cmd = new UdpClient();
            udpClient_Cmd.Client.Bind(IPE_Cmd);
            udpClient_Cmd.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 10);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = false;
            udpClient_Cmd?.Close();
            udpClient_Cmd = null;
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException?.ToString());
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public SPWrapper(IPAddress ip, int cmdPort, string comPort, StreamWriter sw)
    {
        IP = ip;
        Cmd_Port = cmdPort;
        SerialPortName = comPort;
        swLog = sw;
        CmdSerialPort = new SerialPort();
    }

    public bool Init()
    {
        return (InitializeEthernet() && InitilizeSerialPort(SerialPortName));
    }

    internal void GetMessage()
    {
        lastComm = DateTime.Now;
        string SerialMessage = "";
        try
        {
            SerialMessage = CmdSerialPort.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
        }
        if (SerialMessage.Length >0)
        {
            SerialMessage = SerialMessage.Trim(' ').Trim('\n').Trim('\r');
            swLog.WriteLine($"{CmdSerialPort.PortName}\t{lastComm}\t{SerialMessage}");
        }
        IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        byte[] receiveBytes = null;
        try
        {
            receiveBytes = udpClient_Cmd?.Receive(ref e);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            udpClient_Cmd?.Close();
            udpClient_Cmd = null;
        }
        catch(SocketException)
        {
        }
        if (receiveBytes != null)
        {
            string UDP_Read_Message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes.Skip(Ethernet_Packet_Header_Length).ToArray());
            swLog.WriteLine($"{e}\t{lastComm}\t{UDP_Read_Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the exception happen? Examine the stack-trace and or debug the program. If there really is a timeout-exception I can't imagine it being at `blabla = args[4]`, that could only throw a nullreference- or a indexoutofrange exception I think (maybe more but not a timeout-exception). If your app just hangs and there is no exception you should rewrite and specify "timeout error".

Comment: @Joelius "I can't imagine it being at blabla = args[4]" well me to that is why I ask for help since I already traced it and it clearly starts giving error after that line. I uploaded image to make things more clear.

Comment: How did you _trace_ it? It clearly states in the bottom left of your picture that the Exception happens in System.IO.Ports which, I can asure you, has nothing to do with that line you identified as the issue. The error most likely happens in one of `SPWrapper`s methods. Btw is there any multithreading going on? Also, can you post the code of `SPWrapper`?

Comment: @Joelius I put breakpoints in main and watched stack to see which lines are called, it is not multithread, I uploaded SPWrapper, but I don't call its methods yet how can it be possible

Comment: Have you tried actually stepping through the program line by line? You watched the stack which is all well and good but probably not detailed enough for what we're trying to find here. You should step through the main method line by line (F11 in VS, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)) until you get to the error.

Comment: @Joelius I detect something, the problem is with serial port, after open() , it starts to give exceptions because it is caught by UnauthorizedAccessException. I am searching ways to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion with you in the comments, I think I can answer your question.

The error definitely doesn't have anything to do with that line you suspected as you have found out yourself.

You receive a `TimeoutException` which makes sense because in `InitilizeSerialPort` you set the read-timeout to 10ms. That's extremely short, especially considering that you are reading a full line, not just a few bytes.
You really use a bigger number there. The default is 500ms which is quite a good time. If you really need to go lower, try it but in most scenarios you don't need to change that. Since you're reading a full line it's actually very possible that 500ms won't be enough depending on how much information you get per line. Try out some values until it works (but don't set it to 100 if 90 is just enough, give it a bit of room).

Maybe worth mentioning, the timeout is of course the maximum. If you specify 1000ms and the read takes 100ms it will return after 100ms and not wait for the timeout.
To solve the issue you can either completely remove the line where you set the `ReadTimeout`-property (it will use the default of 500ms) or set it to something higher yourself.

Sadly, I can't help you with the `UnauthorizedAccessException` you mentioned in the last comment because that very much depends on your setup. If you need help with that you should ask a new question.

EDIT:
Btw, you're swallowing the `TimeoutException` entirely in `GetMessage`. Do not do that. You're already writing a console-message when another error happens so just do that there too. Same goes for the `SocketException` which is just swallowed in the same method. **Never ever swallow Exceptions**.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes you are right, it has nothing to do with UnauthorizedAccessException  but InitilizeSerialPort () method's timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check to make sure that `args[1]`,`args[2]`,etc are what you think they are? Try changing the `args[1]` to `args[0]` and reducing the rest by one `args[2]` -> `args[1]` etc. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755233/passing-command-line-arguments-to-console-application-does-not-work) and [Reference 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments).

Comment: Please read [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: but args[0] is the program name, I printed them, they all seem to get values correct